# Assigning datatypes to columns of temp table

Tags: sql

I have some source table whose column names are known to me and i want to make a temp table with selected columns... But i am not able to find a way on how to obtain there data types while creating temp table

Comment: just check in tempDB

Comment: won't `select * into #temp from sourcetable` work

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database manager, one of the following should work:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 INTO TEMPORARY TABLE mytemp
  FROM source1;
```

or

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemp AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM mysource;
```

should do it.